# aggregate has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c, struct, g++

I've been stumped over this one:

SpanLogger_c.h

```
#ifndef SPANLOGGERCH
#define SPANLOGGERCH

struct CSpan
{
    int64_t trace_id;
};

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "SpanLogger_c.h"

int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) {
  struct CSpan span;
}
```

compilation command:

```
g++ -g -I. main.c
```

I get this error

```
main.c: In function ‘int main(int, char* const*)’:
main.c:7: error: aggregate ‘CSpan span’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

Anybody help?

Comment: How can the error message be for line 7 when main.c only has 5 lines?  Is that actually what main.c looks like?  Also, why are you compiling a `.c` file with a C++ compiler?

Comment: There a couple of blank lines at the top. I'm trying to debug a larger project. I just tried gcc, and it works fine. Does'nt work with g++

Comment: `g++` is for C++ programs; `gcc` is for C programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SpanLogger_c.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

If you're intending to write C++ use:

```
#include <cstdint>
```

Comment: It's <cstdint> for C++